# Updating Data in UITableView from Strings in Another UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Basically I have two View Controllers: a master and a detail. I'd like for a string inputted in the detail controller to be displayed in a table in the master. In the master controller

I have:

- a NSMutableArray property called names
- a prepareForSegque method that delegates back
- a method to get the string from the 2nd controller:

  -(void) detailViewControllerAdd:(DetailViewController *)detailViewController{

  ```
      [self.names addObject:detailViewController.name];
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    }
  ```
- and a UITableView:

  ```
  -(UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath{

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.textLabel.text = self.names[indexPath.row];
        return cell;
  }

  -(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section
  {
        return self.names.count;
  }
  ```

In my second ViewController (detail) I have a textfield and an "add" button. I'd like for the textfield text to be added into the table rows of the master view controller.

```
-(IBAction)addButton: (id)sender
{
     self.name = self.nameTextField.text;
     [self.delegate detailViewControllerAdd:self];
}
```

Sorry if that's confusing, I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. I know the names are being added fine because I can see them in `NSLog`. I've also tried looking up people's suggestions but `[tableView reloadData]` doesn't work at all, and `[self.tableView]` doesn't even exist.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Also, the segue action is 'modal' if that helps.

Comment: The problem is the way you load the table. Try to search how to display an UITableView or you can see the link: http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/

Comment: Thank you sahara108, that link really helped and it's all good now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) very popular question. showing passing data between view controllers.Surely it will help.

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRow, you should create cell if don't have a reusable cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath{

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
      if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
      }

      cell.textLabel.text = self.names[indexPath.row];
      return cell;
}
```

if you don't want to check `cell == nil`, you should use `- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` which is available above iOS6.